Riemann Sum vs Quadrature
Is it accurate to say that:
Riemann sum leads to the following approximation methods:

Left sum.
Right sum.
Midpoint sum.

As Riemann sum uses the function value $f(x_i^*) \;$ where $\quad x_{i-1} \leq x_i^* \leq x_i \quad$
whereas
Quadrature uses weighted sum of function values at more than one node which leads to the following approximation methods:

Trapezoidal rule.
Simpson’s 1/3 rule.
Simpson’s 3/8 rule. etc. ?

In other words, is it accurate to consider Riemann sum and Quadrature two different approaches that don’t have common approximation methods?
Or can we say that Quadrature is an expansion of Riemann sum and that Quadrature includes Riemann sum approximation methods in addition to the weighted sum approximation methods?

Related (maybe a duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553484/difference-between-quadrature-rules-and-riemann-sum

Quadrature methods (or numerical integration methods or however else you prefer to call them) consist of basically any means of (in this case) approximating the value of integrals. A finite Riemann sum (for a particular partition and set of evaluation points) consists of such a method, since they approximate the integral. (Not very well, necessarily, but an approximation nonetheless.) Simpson's rule, etc., also are considered such.
That is to say, quadrature methods do not require the consideration of multiple nodes, though they certainly could.
(For instance, Wikipedia explicitly states a method of quadrature as the midpoint rule - link.)
